# how to convert string to int[] and retrieve the array for further processing

Tags: java, arrays

```java
String s="7979, 333, 222, 9999";
```

I want to convert the String above to an array:

```java
int[] con = {7979,333,222,999};
```

and use this array further

Here is my code:

```java
Object[] array = arrayList.toArray();
String  sta= (Arrays.toString(array));
String stb= sta.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]","");
tv.setText(stb);
System.out.println(stb);

int[] numbers = Arrays.asList(numbersArray.split(","))
    .stream()
    .map(String::trim)
    .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
    .toArray();
```

Comment: What you tried so far ?

Comment: So far i got the above string from an arraylist and converted it to String s , I have used streams to convert but i got stuck and many other snippets i just dont seem to get it

Comment: Add the code you tried in your post to show your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string using `.split()` method and parse string into int using `parseInt`

```
int[] val = Arrays.stream(s.split(", ")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "7979, 333, 222, 9999";

        int[] nums = Arrays.stream(s.split("\\s*,\\s*")) // Split the string on comma preceded/followed by optional whitespace(s)
                .mapToInt(e -> Integer.parseInt(e)) // Get an IntStream by mapping each string into an integer
                .toArray(); // Convert the IntStream to array

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[7979, 333, 222, 9999]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple method of String Class to achieve what you are trying, one of them is to use `spit()` method.

```
String s="7979, 333, 222, 9999";

String [] stringArray = s.split(",");

//or use followig to remove any blank spaces. 
String[] stringArray = s.split("\\s*,\\s*");

int []con = new int[stringArray.length()];         //initialize int array

//iterate array to convert string to integer 
for(int i=0; i<con.length();i++{
    con[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[i]);
}
```

int []con will have the desired results. There could be many other optimal ways as well to achieve the same.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

Use the method split(",") to convert your string to an array of string separated by the coma value.

Then you should loop into your created array and add into an int list the result of Integer.parseint(your string)

I wont type any code so you keep searching a bit